# distribution function of time T

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

an ambulance station is located 30 miles from one end of a 100-mile road. the station services accidents along the entire road. suppose that an accident occurs. suppose that Suppose accidents occur with uniform distribution along the road and suppose that the ambulance travels 60 miles per hour. Let T be the amount of time it takes the ambulance to arrive at the sence with the assumption that the ambulance leaves the station right after the accident occurs.  find the distribution function FT(t) and the density function Ft(t)

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: find the distribution function FT(t) and the density function Ft(t)

Comment: That's an order, not a question.

Comment: @joriki: Why not just politely explain your issue with his grammer?

Comment: We're slowly turning into Chegg: same copy/paste question [here](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/ambulance-station-located-30-miles-end-100-mile-road-station-services-accidents-entire-roa-q4053541), grammatical errors and all.

Comment: @Jim: I thought I was being about an order of magnitude more polite than the OP. What do you find impolite about my comments? And in particular, why do you find their level of politeness inappropriate given the imperative tone of the OP and its repetition when it was pointed out? I don't see this as an issue of grammar. Are you suggesting that all the people who are copy-pasting error-ridden problems into this site in the imperative are not sufficiently proficient in English to know the difference between a question and an imperative?

Comment: @joriki: Order of magnitude?  I think you're taking this way to personally if that's the case.  It's completely common in mathematics to phrase questions in the imperitive.  I don't know why you would expect someone who's making their first post on this site to magically know that that's considered taboo here, but I don't think it's unreasonable to just directly tell them that you like them not to use the imperitive instead of making an indirect comment.  You complain that the OP used the imperitive in response, but you never asked him not to.  You got a direct, fair, answer to your statement.

Comment: @Jim: You're reducing an important problem on this site to a mere grammatical form. That's not what it's about. If the OP had quoted an exercise formulated in the imperative and then added "I don't know how to get started; please help me by providing some clues" (which is also a (politely phrased) imperative), noone would have complained. I find it rather rude to just dump a problem here, not even bother to proofread it, not even bother to address us, not even bother to ask for anything specific. I don't want to spend my time being overly polite to someone who shows so little respect.

Comment: @Jim: On a meta-level, I find your comments quite paradoxical. You're complaining about me not being polite enough, but when I point out that the OP was far less polite, you say I'm taking this way too personally. Why is considering my level of politeness sensible whereas considering the OP's level of politeness is taking things personally?

Comment: @joriki: I don't think asking a question in the imperitive is impolite in a mathematical context such as this site.  And make no mistake, I'm not complaining about you being *polite enough*, I'm complaining about you being *rude*.

Comment: @Jim: Did you read my comments above?

Comment: @joriki: Also, don't forget that it was you who reduced this problem to a grammatical form by complaining that the OP gave an order instead of asking a question.

Comment: @Jim: I made curt comments without making an effort to explain more precisely what the problem was. I didn't feel like making an effort, because the OP wasn't making an effort. The fact that my curt comments referred only to grammatical categories doesn't imply that the problem can be reduced to a grammatical problem. You and I are engaging in more detailed arguments, and in these, the problem shouldn't be reduced to grammar.

Comment: @joriki: Your comment was not simply curt, it was rude.  Curt would be something like "Don't use the imperative".  Or, if the question isn't worth your time you could have said nothing at all.  Instead you decided to leave a passive agressive comment.  And the fact that the OP answered your comment directly instead of intuiting your meaning should tell you everything about their grasp of English.  Do you really think they were being intentionally rude when they answered your comment using the imperative?

Comment: @Jim: I'm not saying that they were being intentionally rude. People are rarely intentionally rude. If you're right and I was rude, then I, too, wasn't being intentionally rude. What I'm saying is that the manner in which this question was posted, like so many other questions drowning this site, is disrespectful, be it intentional or not. My comment was intended to make the OP think about what they were doing, in this case without spending a lot of time. (Often I do spend a lot of time explaining things to people.) One possible interpretation of their response is lack of English proficiency...

Comment: However, from my experience with the site, the more likely interpretation is lack of respect and interest in meaningful interaction with the site. In the present case, this is confirmed by the unannounced cross-paste that Douglas found, which to me is far more rude than any language style (the OP's or mine); it wastes everyone's time by needlessly duplicating efforts, and this is something everyone without any language skills could easily understand. It's also confirmed by the fact that the OP hasn't responded to, let alone shown appreciation for, André's detailed answer.

Comment: I agree that if the OP had done everything right and there was no problem to point out, only a harmless language barrier, my comments would have been inappropriate. I did respond to what I perceived as lack of respect, and if you don't share that perception, my response naturally appears inappropriate. So I guess our difference starts not with the assessment of my comments but with the assessment of the post (and the OP's comment).

Comment: @Jim: I think I forgot to thank you for telling me about how you perceived my comments; I'll try to take this into account in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Let random variable $X$ be the **distance** the ambulance has to travel. The time $T$ is then $\frac{X}{60}$. We will find the distribution of $X$. From that it is not hard to find the distribution of $T$. We do $X$ instead of $T$ for two reasons: (i) It is closer to the intuition and (ii) There might as well be something left for you to do.

We will find the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ of the random variable $X$. Recall that $F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x)$.

First let's knock off the easy stuff. If $x\lt 0$, then $F_X(x)=0$. (The probability that the ambulance has to travel $\le -17$ miles is $0$. Also, if $x\gt 70$, then $F_X(x)=1$ (for sure the ambulance will have to travel fewer than $88$ miles).

So from now on we confine attention to $0\le x\le 70$. Because of the non-central location of the ambulance, we need to break up this interval.

Suppose $0\le x\le 30$. The ambulance has to travel a distance $\le x$ if te accident takes place within $\le x$ miles from the normal position of the ambulance. This is an interval of length $2x$, so the probability the accident takes place in this interval is $\frac{2x}{100}$.

In symbols, $F_X(x)=\frac{2x}{100}$ if $0\le x\le 30$.

Now suppose that $30\lt x\le 70$. Then we have to travel $\le x$ if (i) the accident takes place within $30$ miles of the ambulance (probability $\frac{60}{100}$) or the accident takes place at a distance between $30$ and $x$ from the ambulance (probability $\frac{x-30}{100}$. Add the two probabilities.

Thus if $30\lt x\le 0$, then $F_X(x)=\frac{x+30}{100}$.

Now we have the cdf. Differentiate to get the density. there are points of non-differentiability at $0$, $30$, and $70$, but we won't worry about them We get $f_X(x)=0$ if $x\lt 0$ and also if $x\gt 70$. For $0\le x\le 30$, $f_X(x)=\frac{2}{100}$. For $30\lt x\le 70$, $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{100}$.

**Remark:** For your homework problem, you can either imitate the analysis, using $T$ or (easier) directly write down the cdf and density of $T$ (they are close relatives of the cdf and density of $X$.)